# Avoid Multiple Nested For Each Loops

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I am new to C# and taking my first course at a University.  I think this is an issue with `instantiation` but here goes with what I am after.

I am wanting to get the value from `te.ED` w/o having to go through the multiple `for each` loops, as if the answer is "No" then there is no need to go through the loops and extract multiple data elements (not being shown).  Is there a way to check that value **BEFORE** going through all of the `for each` loops?

Code is here

```
TR reply = service.track(request);
foreach (CTD ctd in reply.CTD)
{
    foreach (TD td in ctd.TD)
    {
        if (td.Events != null)
        {
            foreach (TE te in td.Events)
            {
                if (te.TimestampSpecified)
                {
                    //This is where the field I am after exists
                    if (te.ED == "YES")
                        Console.WriteLine("The answer is yes");
                    else 
                        Console.WriteLine("The answer is no");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Per the comment from @Anis Programmer - I believe you are wanting to see the `TD` element from the class `CTD`.  If that is the case - see below

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TD")]
public TD[] TD {
    get { return this.tdf; }
    set { this.tdf = value; }
}
```

Per the answer from @Neel below - I am very close with the syntax

```
var result = reply.CTD.SelectMany(c1 => c1.TD)
                  .SelectMany(c2 => c2.Events.Select(c3 => c3.TimestampSpecified));


foreach (var ltr in result)
    Console.WriteLine(ltr)
```

Now the issue is that the `foreach` loop makes two passes, and the value returned from both is `True`

What do I need to change in this syntax?

Comment: You do not need to abbreviate you variable names so much! Especially when learning use **full** words that describe what they are for. It will make it easier for you and anyone who reads your code in the future to decipher what is happening.

Comment: good idea.  I was thinking the less I type out the more efficient it would be.  However, as you stated if no one can follow what is going on, or decipher it, it costs more in the long run.

Comment: Very unclear what you are trying to achieve - you've posted some code (which is good start), but did not explain what you want that code to do (rather than how it does that). Also check out [MCVE] guidance on posting code - following it would have helped everyone to see what types are used in the code. Possibly `Enumerable.First` is the answer, but hard to say without information on what code is expected to do.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I want to check the value of te.ED **WITHOUT** having to use all of the for loops to get there.  Does that help clarify?

Comment: Could you please show us the values of reply.CTD

Comment: @anisprogrammer - do you want to see this class (CTD)?  Is that what you are asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a LinQ in a `foreach` like this:

```
foreach (
    var te in from ctd in reply.CTD
    from td in ctd.TD
    where td.Events != null
    from te in td.Events
    where te.TimestampSpecified
    select te)
{
    Console.WriteLine(te.ED == "YES" ? "The answer is yes" : "The answer is no");
}
```

Comment: That got it!  The only tweak I had to make was to change the syntax to `reply.CTD`

Answer (score 1):

What I assumed from the example you have posted that you want to avoid multiple nested foreach loop.

You can use linq to shorten the same.Here is how using lamda expression.

```
var result = reply
    .SelectMany(c1 => c1.CTD)
    .SelectMany(c2 => c2.TD)
    .SelectMany(c3 => c3.Events.Select(c4 => c4.TimestampSpecified));
```

Now you just loop on the result and compare with `ED` value.

Comment: I would just need to loop like such?  --- if `(timestampspec.ED == "Yes")`

Comment: result would be a collection of `Events` with `TimestampSpecified` property.

Comment: If I type `var result = reply` intellisense does not show `SelectMany` as an option

Comment: Yes, I have `using System.Linq` in my project.

Comment: I figured it out.  I have to use `reply.CTD.SelectMany` and place this under the first `foreach`

Comment: using a `foreach` - it is always null?